# How to disable a proxy when using the Guzzle HTTP client?

Tags: php, proxy, guzzle

I'm trying to call a web service on a clients server using the Guzzle library - but the server have a proxy so I'm getting a 404 error in my code.

If I ssh into the clients server and try

```
wget http://www.mywebsite.com/mywebservice
```

I get an error

```
Resolving proxy.theirdomainname.com (proxy.theirdomainname.com)... xx.xx.xx.xx
Connecting to proxy.theirdomainname.com (proxy.theirdomainname.com)|xx.xx.xx.xx|:80...
failed: Connection timed out.
```

But if I use

```
wget --no-proxy http://www.mywebsite.com/mywebservice
```

I get a result

```
Resolving www.mywebsite.com (www.mywebsite.com)... xx.xx.xx.xx
Connecting to www.mywebsite.com (www.mywebsite.com)|xx.xx.xx.xx|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
```

I can see an option to set the proxy in the Guzzle documentation  - http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/http-client/client.html#proxy

But how do I disable using a proxy altogether? Or will this be a server setting?

EDIT:

```
$request = $client->get($this->url(), array('proxy' => ''))
                  ->setHeader('Accept', 'text/xml');

$response = $request->send();
var_dump($response);
```

Result :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException'
with message 'Client error response [status code] 404 [reason phrase] Not Found [url] http://mywebsite.com'
in /vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Exception/BadResponseException.php:44 
Stack trace: #0 /guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Request.php(145): Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException::factory(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Request), Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response)) 
#1 [internal function]: Guzzle\Http\Message\Request::onRequestError(Object(Guzzle\Common\Event))
#2 /vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(164): call_user_func(Array, Object(Guzzle\Common\Event))
#3 /vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(53): Symfony in /vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Exception/BadResponseException.php on line 44
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you should be aware that the proxy server is not something "they have". It is part of the network configuration on YOUR side.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear - it is their server rather than ours.

Comment: You didn't show the code where request is made using Guzzle. Reading the docs, I found that you can pass proxy config to the `get()` method. Would this not help? `$client->get('/', ['proxy' => '']);` Link: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#proxy

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Guzzlehttp6 :

- if you want to specify a different proxy for a given type of protocol :

  ```
   $client->request('GET', 'your_url_here', [
  'proxy' => [
  'http'  => 'tcp://localhost:8125', // Use this proxy with "http"
  'https' => 'tcp://localhost:9124', // Use this proxy with "https",
  'no' => ['.mit.edu', 'foo.com']    // Don't use a proxy with these
     ]
  ]);
  ```
- If you want to disable proxy for all your queries :

  ```
  $client->request('GET','your_url_here',['proxy'=>'']);
  ```

  [Link to the official documentation.](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#proxy)

Comment: This works, should be the accepted answer. Another solution is setting `CURLOPT_PROXY` to false via the (Guzzle) Client constructor options: https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/client.html#configuration-options

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Guzzle\Client` auto-magically sets the proxy looking at your system environment variables. It doesn't matter if you're on Linux or Windows:

```
  280:         // Use the standard Linux HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY if set
  281:         if ($proxy = getenv('HTTP_PROXY')) {
  282:             $settings['proxy']['http'] = $proxy;
  283          }
  284  
  285:         if ($proxy = getenv('HTTPS_PROXY')) {
  286:             $settings['proxy']['https'] = $proxy;
  287          }
```

So if you previously set your proxy using something like

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://your.proxy.local:8080
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://your.proxy.local:8080
```

then this proxy setting will be picked up.

You have to enforce an empty proxy like Marcell Fülöp said.

Comment: Can you also mention how to turn off the proxy